# Les moisissures viennent d’en dessous le plancher/ d’au-dessous le plancher/ d’en bas

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Quelle serait la meilleure énonciation?

> Les moisissures viennent d’en dessous le plancher.

> Les moisissures viennent d’au-dessous le plancher.

> Les moisissures viennent d’en bas, sous le plancher.

Autre formulation à proposer? Reformulation nécessaire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toutes les formulations proposées sont compréhensibles, mais pour moi, utiliser *"en dessous **le**"* au lieu de *"en dessous **de**"* fait un peu vieillot (vieux parler populaire/patois).

Le dernière phrase me semble tout à fait naturelle (pour du français de France), mais voici comment j'aurais spontanément formulé cela :

> - Les moisissures viennent d'en dessous du plancher.
> - Les moisissures viennent de sous le plancher.

Comment: En réalité il s’agit d’une faute de frappe, j’avais l’intention d’écrire en dessous/au-dessous de/du!

Comment: Pour éviter que ma question vienne rendre nulle ta réponse, je vais la laisser telle quelle.

Comment: @Jean-LouFrenette Ah ok merci alors.

Answer (score 0):

On pourrait aussi dire :

> les moisissures viennent du dessous du plancher.